# Correct cross-compilation options to run binary on Raspberry 3 model B

Tags: pi-3, linux, cross-compilation, arm, software-compilation

I have Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with me. I am developing on Ubuntu Linux laptop computer. I want to cross-compile so that the binary may run on Raspberry. My Raspberry info:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor   : 1
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor   : 2
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor   : 3
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : a22082
Serial      : 0000000034e8fca4
Model       : Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lscpu
Architecture:        armv7l
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           ARM
Model:               4
Model name:          Cortex-A53
Stepping:            r0p4
CPU max MHz:         1200.0000
CPU min MHz:         600.0000
BogoMIPS:            44.80
Flags:               half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
```

So I want to know about cross-compiler and its options:

1. Which cross-compiler will work for me ? `arm-none-eabi-` or `arm-linux-gnueabihf-` ? And also whats the difference ?
2. Which CPU option `-mcpu` should I use ? `-mcpu=cortex-a53` or `-mcpu=generic-armv7-a` or something else ?
3. The docs say that on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, the system chip is `BCM2837`, but I see that its showing as  `BCM2835`. Why so ?

I would appreciate answers to any/all of my questions please. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need the `linux` variant. `none` indicates a bare metal target.
2. I use `-mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard` for the [`armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf`](https://github.com/tttapa/docker-arm-cross-toolchain/blob/master/cmake/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf.toolchain.cmake) toolchain I maintain.
3. https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-revision-codes

> All Raspberry Pi computers report BCM2835, even those with BCM2836, BCM2837 and BCM2711 processors. You should not use this string to detect the processor.

Comment: Thanks. But also my R Pi reports armv7 L architecture (which is 32 bit), but you are telling to use armv8 toolchain. Isn't armv8 for 64-bit ??

Comment: @AlphaParticle ARMv8 only refers to the hardware revision, it does not imply a bitness. The ARMv8-A Cortex-A53 hardware supports both the AArch64 and AArch32 architectures. You seem to be using a 32-bit operating system, so you need a 32-bit toolchain, which is `armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf`. If you were using a 64-bit operating system (which is supported by your hardware), you would use the 64-bit toolchain `aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu`. See https://github.com/tttapa/docker-arm-cross-toolchain/tree/master#download for details.

Comment: Is it correct to say that since `arm-none-eabi-` is for bare metal - so it will create the complete image during (cross-compilation) build consisting of boot files and linker script. That is `arm-none-eabi-` requires boot files of hardware platform and also linker script to place different sections. Whereas since `arm-linux-gnueabihf-` is NOT bare metal so it won't require boot files and linker script of the hardware platform during cross-compilation build.

Comment: @AlphaParticle see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956680/difference-between-arm-none-eabi-and-arm-linux-gnueabi